# How to add an advanced Filter (via CSS or SVG) on Background for my website

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, graphics

This is a question about filters to apply to images.
I state that I am not a programmer, and that I have just started reading something about svg images. I know the CSS better.

**I'm trying to make a new homepage for my site.
I need a background image with an original effect.**

I would like to know if via CSS or SVG it is possible to use img: hover to modify ONLY a portion of the image, for example a radius of 200px around the mouse cursor...

**For example, the background image is colored, and when the mouse is over the image, I would like only a certain portion of the image to be affected by the filter I want to apply, in this case a circle of 200px around the mouse that ad example becomes black and white, or blurs, etc...**

**Would it be possible to create this effect, using 2 overlapping images and a mask that moves together the mouse cursor? (via css maybe?)**

And if this circle also had the nuance it would be even better.

Is it possible through CSS or SVG to obtain this effect?

I am attaching a photo, which may be clearer to understand ...
Thank you all.

[image]

Comment: You could try your own idea! Have two background images. One is masked and only shows the part where a small circle (the mask) is. The circle moves when the mouse moves. Why don't you try it out? You can google for CSS mask and for mouse move listeners.

Comment: can you add some code ?

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT: Added interactive hotspot**

Here's a rudimentary solution:

1. Create a container with relative position and place two overlapping images inside.
2. Add a hover effect to the hotspot image.
3. Add event listener to get the current mouse position on the image and set the `clip-path` property of the hotspot accordingly.

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const hotspot = document.querySelector('.hotspot');

function moveHotspot(event) {
  const containerRect = event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
  const y = event.clientY - containerRect.top;
  const x = event.clientX - containerRect.left;
  hotspot.style.clipPath = `circle(8.5% at ${x}px ${y}px)`;
}

container.addEventListener('mousemove', moveHotspot);
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 640px;
  height: 360px;
}

.image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXFUq.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}

.hotspot:hover {
  -webkit-filter: hue-rotate(210deg) brightness(1.5);
  filter: hue-rotate(210deg) brightness(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='image'></div>
  <div class='image hotspot'></div>
</div>
```